# Term to describe users' initial dislike of user interface change

Tags: terminology

What is the best term to describe the fact that most users have an initial dislike of any change to a UI even though it may really be net better over time?

*Note: Question originally appeared [as a  Google+ post here.](https://plus.google.com/106920059607812615730/posts/HHqfhqLoP4j)*

Answer (score 5):

*Resistance to change* is a general expression that can also be used in the case of UIs.

Answer (score 1):

[Prejudice](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prejudice) *- "preconceived opinion" (especially but not necessarily unfavorable)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe them as having *inertia* that must be overcome.